# (wit.ai) Is it possible to add keyword to wit/location using the http api?

Tags: http, wit.ai

I used the following method (https://wit.ai/docs/http/20160526#post--entities-:entity-id-values-link) to add a keyword to a user defined entity, and it worked. However, when I did this to add a keyword to wit/location (one of the built-in entities in wit.ai), it did not work.

How do I add a keyword to wit/location using the http api?

Is there another way I can add keywords to wit/location automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking. This is actually not possible. wit/location is a built-in entity, which means it is trained across many Wit apps. Since this is used by thousands of Wit apps, we want to be careful with the HTTP API. Why do you need to add keywords for wit/location? You have 2 options:

- Validate via the console some examples (here this is more where the wit/location is located in these examples than the current keyword itself).
- Create your own custom location entity

Comment: I have a list of location name, so I want to import this list into the wit.ai model. I actually tried to create a custom location entity, but it seems that this custom entity is "overwhelmed" by wit/location. I tried to send some request with the location name in my list included in the sentence, but it was not detected as my custom entity.